# print callstack on every C++ exception throw in lldb

Tags: c++, exception, lldb

I'm using lldb and I'd like to catch all C++ based exceptions and print the callstack of the current thread for each breakpoint automatically, and continue.

This will stop on all exceptions `break set -E C++`, but how can set an automation that will print the callstack (bt command) and automatically continue?

Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all available as options to the break set command (see `help break set` for even more options).  You want:

```
break set -E C++ -G 1 -C "bt"
```

You can also change the commands on a breakpoint after creation with the `breakpoint command add` command.